# How to add custom style to menu items in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I made a navigation drawer following a youtube video.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:background="@color/menuColor"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
      app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
      app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
      app:paddingStart="20px"
      app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">


  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is custom drawermenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:title="Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:title="First item" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:title="Second Item"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

How can I add custom fonts and font sizes for the items like - Making the "Title" with a size of 26sp and other items with a size of 18sp. How can I also make them centered and also add padding to it?

I tried doing that from the design interface but it doesn't have any of those options. Using android:layout_gravity="center" that did not work for me either.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, Can you please share it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to having the

```
android:actionMenuTextAppearance
```

item under your action bar style, move it under your app theme.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to strings.xml from values folder. Here for size their are different terms like  and  and to change font face you can use **face** inside font tag.

```
<resources>
<string name="history"><big><font face="serif" color="#303030">History</font></big></string>
<string name="favourites"><big><font color="#303030">Favourites</font></big></string>
</resource>
```

And change below one where you add menuitems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/history"
    android:title="@string/history" />
<item android:id="@+id/favourites"
    android:title="@string/favourites"/>
</menu>
```

[image: Here you can see the font for history and favourites are different]